# Encrypted command line

Tags: windows, encryption, command-line, command-prompt

I have a situation where I need to give a bunch of administrators a command to run from a Windows command line that contains a password. There is no workaround for this application to avoid having a password on the command line.

For example:

c:>mycommand -P mypassword

I just want to give them an encrypted string that decrypts to "mycommand -P mypassword" and executes that command with its parameters without displaying the unencrypted text.

Say like this:

c:>mycommanddecoder efouhpefibhusdvn,iu3r3ksjdfdfbpisiegf

I've googled but results tend to come up with PGP command line utilities and the like.

I could just write a custom executable to do the job but that wouldn't stop a savvy operator  from viewing the object code. I could encrypt it internally but then there would still be a visible key unless I used a certificate ... and you get the idea. It quickly becomes a mission!

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that in the end you want the script / program / command line to result in a system call that spawns the `mycommand` executive with the password as a parameter. And this syscall can be observed. Whatever you do beforehand you will not get around this attack point. You probably should look for a solution where the password never needs to be stored on the computer at all, maybe outsource the functionality into a service running somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good point. In this particular case, the attack vector has a very brief life and the people that will be doing this anyway are employees. We're just trying to minimise the number of people with the knowledge of this password. Unfortunately the vendor of this software is a royal PITA that has no clue about security and we are just trying to minimise the impact.